# Multiple asynchronous Google Maps onclick

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load different Google Maps depending on what link they click. Something like this:

First, a user clicks a link like...

```
<a class="loadMap" href="?map&center=44.370987,-85.407715">load map 1</a>
```

...or...

```
<a class="loadMap" href="?map&center=23.4567,-80.234523">load map 2</a>
```

The Google Maps API is then loaded asynchronously (if it hasn't been loaded already). The map center is taken from the href of the link clicked, and then the map is displayed right below the link that was clicked (something in jQuery like **$(this).after(showMap);**)

I've found examples that [load a single map asynchronously](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dynamicloading/scriptappend.html), but I can't figure out how to pass different map parameters to load a different map and place it relative to the link that was clicked.

Comment: To clarify, are the links dynamic (user can pick center) or static?

Comment: The links each contain different parameters to a different map center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **demo:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/multiple-asynchronous-google-maps-onclick/

```
        function initialize(map_id, lat, lng) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom : 8,
                center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_id), myOptions);
        }

        $(function() {
            $('.loadMap').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var cooordinates = this.hash.split('=')[1].split(',');
                var lat = cooordinates[0];
                var lng = cooordinates[1];
                var map = this.id + '-map';

                if($('#maps_canvas #' + map).length === 0) {
                    $('<div class="map_style" id="' + map + '">').appendTo('#maps_canvas');
                    initialize(map, lat, lng);
                }
            });
        });
```

> - **NOTE:** see demo source for full code

Comment: This is a start (I'll play with it), but I need it to dynamically create a new map on the existing page. So user clicks a link, that map is created right below the link they clicked (without page refresh). Potentially they could be looking at multiple maps at the same time if they click more than one link.

Comment: @Michael: Multiple asynchronous have nothing to do with what you need then, see the demo and source i have updated it.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!! That's exactly what I need. I have to play with it a bit to get the maps to insert precisely where I need them, but I can figure that much out.